# Taylor series has bounds, but what about Laurent series?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, laurent-series, upper-lower-bounds

For a Taylor series, we have Lagrange remainders:

$$\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}(x-a)^k\right|\le\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(\xi)|}{(n+1)!}|x-c|^{n+1},\ |\xi-c|\le x$$

But do we have a similar thing for Laurent series?

$$\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=-n}^na_k(x-c)^k\right|\le~?$$

$$\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=-\infty}^na_k(x-c)^k\right|\le~?$$

$$\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=-n}^{+\infty}a_k(x-c)^k\right|\le~?$$

Such would be fairly useful for solving limits with a squeeze theoerem, for example.

Comment: Subtracting off the principal part gives you an analytic function, after which you can do whatever you like with Taylor series. If you don't have the entire principal part and you have a pole of order $n$, you can look at the analytic function $f(z)(z-c)^n$.

Comment: @Chappers Ah, so: $$g(z)=f(z)-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}a_k(z-c)^k$$and build bounds from there, or likewise, $$g(z)=f((z+c)^{-1})-\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{-k}z^{-k}$$?

Comment: Not sure you want the $()^{-1}$ in the second one, but yes, that's one idea.

Comment: @Chappers If you'd like, you could post an answer so I may accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are extensions of this idea, although they rely on converting the function to an analytic one (although given that Taylor's Theorem is a quite complicated extension of the Mean Value Theorem, we should perhaps not be too concerned about this). Two possible approaches:

- If $P(z)$ is the principal part of the Laurent series, then $g(z)=f(z)-P(z)$ is analytic, and so has the ordinary sort of Taylor polynomial and remainder,
  $$ g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{g^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(z-a)^k + R_n[g](z), $$
  where $R_n[g](z)$ has your favourite expression.
- If $f(z)$ has a pole of order $n$ at $a$, then $h(z)=(z-a)^n f(z)$ is an analytic function, so it has the usual Taylor formula,
  $$ h(z) = \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{h^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(z-a)^k + R_N[h](z). $$
  One may then divide both sides of this by $(z-a)^n$ to find a Taylor-like formula for $f$.

Neither of these are especially useful for a couple of reasons: firstly, complex-analytic/holomorphic functions come with infinitely many derivatives for free, and have Taylor series that converge absolutely inside the disc or annulus of convergence, so there is not much need to having a finite formula that applies to more limiting circumstances. Secondly, integral estimates based on the Residue Theorem tend to be much more useful in complex analysis since one can deform the contour in helpful ways with much more freedom. Such estimates also only need to use $f$, not its derivatives.

Comment: Well, the main purpose of this was to find good enough bounds on a particular real limit I was trying to take, and I ended up stumbling upon a Laurent series that satisfied my problem and wondered if we could make bounds on Laurent series in general.  But anyways, good answer.